# BAD ACCESS when trying to loop through Core Data has many

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a class called Interaction that more or less manages the NSManagedObject and keeps state for me in throughout the app.

```
// In IntroViewController
AppDelegate *applicationDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

applicationDelegate.interaction = [[Interaction alloc] init];
[applicationDelegate.interaction createNewInteractionByCallId:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] programId:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] questionnaireId:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] outletId:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4] userId:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]];
```

So there I setup an instance of the interaction, and use the create method i have there to set up the managed object:

```
- (void)createNewInteractionByCallId:(NSNumber *)callId programId:(NSNumber *)programId questionnaireId:(NSNumber *)questionnaireId outletId:(NSNumber *)outletId userId:(NSNumber *)userId
{    
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self getManagedContext];

    NSManagedObject *interaction = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Interaction" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [interaction setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"date_started"];
    [interaction setValue:[self createGUUID] forKey:@"uuid"];
    [interaction setValue:callId forKey:@"call_id"];
    [interaction setValue:programId forKey:@"program_id"];
    [interaction setValue:questionnaireId forKey:@"questionnaire_id"];
    [interaction setValue:userId forKey:@"user_id"];
    [interaction setValue:outletId forKey:@"outlet_id"];
    [self saveRecord];
    self.managedObject = interaction;
}
```

To describe the entities. An interaction has many answers. Answers relate to a question id on our remote server.

So when i add an answer, i'll check for an answer by the given questionId and update it, or create a new one. This is where things are blowing up:

```
- (void)addAnswerFor:(NSNumber *)questionId questionType:(NSNumber *)questionType formId:(NSNumber *)formId answerText:(NSString *)answerText
{
    NSManagedObject *answer;

    NSMutableSet *answers = [self getAnswers];
    NSArray *answersArray = [answers allObjects];
    for (NSManagedObject *ans in answersArray) {
        if ([ans valueForKey:@"question_id"] == questionId) {
            answer = ans;
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

// Get answers from the Interaction.m

```
- (NSMutableSet *)getAnswers
{
    [self.managedObject mutableSetValueForKey:@"answers"];
}
```

However i get the bad access error on the for loop line:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
```

Do i need to initialize an empty set for the relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `getAnswers` works as expected. I suspect it is `nil`, that would give you such an error. (Still, you should edit your question and post the exact error message.)

No need to convert to `answersArray` before the fast enumeration (there is no sorting).

BTW, if more than one answer matches a question you will overwrite the last result. But I guess that is a case that is not foreseen.

Also, maybe you can get rid of the loop altogether by using a predicate:

```
NSSet *matchingAnswers = [answers filteredSetUsingPredicate:
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"question_id == %@", questionId]];
NSManagedObject *answer = 
  matchingAnswers.count ? matchingAnswers.anyObject : nil;
```

Finally, I think your whole setup with the Interaction class is a bad idea. With all these cumbersome methods passing tons of parameters you are not really encapsulating the logic at all, but actually spreading custom made complexity everywhere. It would be preferable to just write plain Core Data methods into your controllers and dispense with the Interaction class altogether.

Comment: I appreciate the input. Note that NSSet does not seem to have a firstObject propery :). Ended up using anyObject, but like you said that could lead to unexpected behaviour if the interaction has more than one question for a given question_id. I updated my question with the error code, and put in the getAnswers method as well. Any ideas on why that might return nil? I agree the Interaction class itself needs some improvement, but if i kept the logic to the view controllers, would that not lead to a lot of repetitive code across the app?

Comment: Annd i just realized the core issue. I wasnt invoking a return statement in the getAnswers... do'h. I left it broken in the question for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I corrected it into `anyObject`.

Comment: Haven't tried, but i believe you need to invoke it as a method: `[matchingAnswers anyObject]`

Comment: No, I use it with dot notation all the time.